# "Este artigo ou seção está a ser traduzido"

Tags: concordância

[Em um artigo da Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81cido_s%C3%B3rbico), consta esse aviso:

[image: Da Wikipédia]

Parece-me incorreto porque seção é feminino e o sujeito está no plural. Não deveria ser "este artigo ou seção estão a ser traduzidos"?

Comment: Muita gente faz o acordo com o primeiro substantivo quando o primeiro é masculino e o segundo é feminino.

Comment: Eis possivelmente a solução para os teus problemas: https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint54.php.

Comment: @Schilive Obrigado, essa página responde à questão da concordância do verbo; Este se enquadraria no caso excludente. Entretanto, não diz explìcitamente o que fazer com o adjetivo "traduzido", embora o mais natural seria deixar no masculino mesmo.

Comment: @LoremIpsum, imagino que seja "traduzido" pelo masculino ser gênero neutro também. Assim como quando se diz "professores são [...]" não se excluem as professoras. Se quiseres, podes escrever "este artigo ou seção está a traduzir-se".

Comment: Como há um artigo no gênero feminino e outro no masculino, deve ficar no gênero neutro do Português, que é o masculino

Comment: Lembrando que o adjetivo não poderia ser flexionado em número sem que o verbo também concordasse em número; *este artigo ou se(c)ção estão a ser traduzidos* lhe parece natural? Eu concordaria com estas concordâncias se estivesse escrito *artigo **e** se(c)ção*, ou ainda *artigos ou se(c)ções*, mas não da forma como foi apresentada na pergunta.